# How to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH for all users in CentOS, in order to be visible also in screen?

Tags: environment-variables, screen

I have set the LD_LIBARY_PATH in the /etc/profile.d folder of my CentOS distro, and it works properly for all users.

However, when I fire up screen, it does not inherit it. Is there any way to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH for screen for all users (without editing all .bashrc files for all users) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking to set the enviroment variable for the system. Just add it to /etc/environment and when a user logs in the variables will be set.

You'll need root access in order to update it. So make sure to edit with sudo.

/etc/environment

```
LD_LIBRARY="{insert path here}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately this did not work. I had to edit the /etc/bashrc file instead.

Answer (score 1):

The file that needs to be modified is the 
`/etc/bashrc` Now screen can see properly the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable

Answer (score 0):

Add to file with the path to the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`, this is the proper way to do it.